# Firejail or chroot

Tags: security, chroot, sandbox, firejail

What's the difference between Firejail and `chroot` in case of security? I mean, should I trust a built-in tool or third-party for sandboxing untrusted applications that could be potentially targeted to harm or steal something from machine?

Comment: For doing what?

Answer (score 3):

`Firejail` is a sandboxing program with lots of extended functionalities, much far beyond `chroot`. As a side note, you may use `chroot`, but running `firejail` to achieve the same as `chroot` is way simpler, as one of the supported container types in `firejail` can be of type `chroot`.